# What are the numbers in the output of an INSERT statement, and why is the first one zero?

Tags: postgresql, insert

When you `INSERT`, you'll get back something like

```
# CREATE TABLE foo ( a int );
# INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1),(2);
INSERT 0 2
```

What is the first and second number after the `INSERT` (the `0` and the `2`)?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs on `INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

> On successful completion, an `INSERT` command returns a command tag of the form
>
> ```
> INSERT oid count
> ```
>
> The count is the number of rows inserted or updated. *If count is exactly one, **and the target table has OIDs, then oid is the OID assigned to the inserted row. The single row must have been inserted rather than updated. Otherwise oid is zero.***

This is pretty much a legacy feature. PostgreSQL doesn't, by default, assign [OIDs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) to rows anymore. So this feature is only useful if,

- If the table was `CREATE`d  with the option [`WITH OIDS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html).
- If only one row was inserted.

As noted by [Sahap Asci](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/72070/sahap-asci) in the comments, when PostgreSQL 12 drops table creation will no longer even support `WITH OIDS`. From the docs of `WITHOUT OIDS` on [PostgreSQL 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtable.html),

> This is backward-compatible syntax for declaring a table `WITHOUT OIDS`, creating a table `WITH OIDS` is not supported anymore.

Comment: After version 12, oid's can no longer be added to user created tables using the `WITH OIDS` clause.

Comment: @SahapAsci hrm, wonder if v12 will deprecate this verbose output on the INSERT.

Comment: I hope so. And remove it in version 14 or 15.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I just tested insert in v 12 beta and get the same output format `INSERT 0 1`